# Property of object doesn't update the binding

Tags: xml, wpf, data-binding

I have an object, in which i change a property that i want to display in a textblock through a binding.

I.e.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ObjectName.Property}"/>
```

viewmodel:

```
public void MethodToChangeObjectProperty()
{
    //Some random code
    ObjectName.Property = SomeValuetoAdd;
}

public Object ObjectName
{
    get {return _objectName; }
    set 
    {
        _objectName = value;
        NotifyPropertChanged();
    }
}
```

The property is being updated. but the setter is never getting triggered, which means that the value is never reaching my view. I'm sure that the `NotifyPropertyChanged();` is not my problem.

Comment: The setter for `ObjectName.Property` is not the `ObjectName` setter but the `Property` setter - where did you place your breakpoint?

Comment: placed it inside my setter

Comment: @Avacay Which setter? Setter of `ObjectName` or setter of `Property`?

Comment: Object **MUST** use Properties and Implement `INPC` for it to work.

Comment: Is "Object" a `System.Object` or what is it? The object returned by the `ObjectName` property must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the binding to get refreshed when you set any property of `ObjectName`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX thats not entirely true... if you do crazy fancy stuff, you can actually chose to not use INPC and then `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item.GetType())[nameof(MyClass.TestProperty)].SetValue(item, "Hello World");`. However, if you can chose, you should of course always go with `INPC`

Comment: @grek40 thanks for the technical exercise, which would be used when in a serious pinch! And if I saw that code, I would feel more than inclined to delete it. But then How does the UI keeps track of changes, it would require some strong references between VM and V, possibly causing memory leak in the background.

Comment: @XAMlMAX `PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` - I'm not sure, but I guess the UI would use this to register a catch-em-all handler on the instance-agnostic `PropertyDescriptor` and then check whether the event sender is the same as bound object... so there shouldn't be a strong reference to the vm object. Basically, I was just nitpicking on "Object MUST [...] Implement INPC for it to work" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is to `ObjectName.Property`, that means the property where you need to put `NotifyPropertChanged()` is `Property`. `ObjectName` property is not relevant for this case. So, ObjectName class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and `Property` should have `NotifyPropertChanged()` in its own setter.